# floor(log10(a)/log10(b)) is not equal to floor(log(a)/log(b)) for some values

Tags: c++, c++17, clang-11

I can't figure out why *****l10***** variable in code below isn't equal to ***l*** variable for values 243 and 59049 (probably there is some other values).

They are both double values. So I think that the *floor()* function should return same results for both and these results should be equal.

But in *log()* case
floored value decreased by one and in *log10()* case floored value is still the same.

```
#include <typeinfo>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
    {
        double l10 = log10(i)/log10(3);
        double l = log(i)/log(3);
        if (floor(l10) != floor(l)){
            cout << floor(l10) << " " << floor(l) << 
                " types: " << typeid(l10).name() << typeid(l).name() << endl;
            cout << "number: " << i << endl << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
5 4 types: dd
number: 243

10 9 types: dd
number: 59049
```

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://wandbox.org/permlink/2cLFOkgQLZgRCzWj

Comment: [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/588014/4641116)

Comment: @jabaa, it does